# How to merge two arrays when a key of one of them and a value of the other array is match

Tags: php

I am looking for a way to merge two arrays and create two dimension array.

dayArray

```
(
    [1] => tue
    [2] => wed
    [4] => fri
    [5] => sat
```

I would like to assign the values below.

fruitArray

```
array (
  'tue' => 'banana',
  'fri' => 'apple',
  'sat' => 'orange',
)
```

two-dimensional array
expected result

```
  $array = [
　　 1 =>['tue','banana'],
　　 2 =>['wed'],
　　 4 =>['fri','apple'],
     5 =>['sat','orange']
```

I tried to make it

```
{
    foreach ($dayArray as $key => $value)
    {
        if($fruitArray[$value]){
            $dayArray[$key] = array($key,$value,$fruitArray[$value]);
        }
    }
}
```

> ErrorException: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in f

Comment: The exception says one of arrays is null, probably `$fruitArray` is.

Answer (score 1):

```
$dayArr = array(1 => 'tue', 2 => 'wed', 4 => 'fri',5 => 'sat');
$fruitArr = array (
   'tue' => 'banana',
   'fri' => 'apple',
   'sat' => 'orange',
);
$result = array_map(function ($val) use ($fruitArr) {
   return array_key_exists($val, $fruitArr) ? [$val, $fruitArr[$val]] : [$val];
}, $dayArr);
```

With arrow function : (version php >= 7.4)

```
$dayArr = array(1 => 'tue', 2 => 'wed', 4 => 'fri',5 => 'sat');
$fruitArr = array (
   'tue' => 'banana',
   'fri' => 'apple',
   'sat' => 'orange',
);
$result = array_map(fn ($val) => array_key_exists($val, $fruitArr) ? [$val, $fruitArr[$val]] : [$val], $dayArr);
```

Comment: You could also use an arrow function: _fn($item) => array_key_exists($item, $fruitArray) ? [ $item, $fruitArray[$item] ] : [ $item ]_

Comment: I tried like this 
```
$result = array_map( fn($item) => array_key_exists($item, $fruitArray) ? [ $item, $fruitArray[$item] ] : [ $item ],$dayArr);
```

However , ErrorException: Undefined variable: fruitArray in file

Comment: version of php for arrow function need >= 7.4

Answer (score 0):

looks like you forgot to add `isset()` for checking whether key is exist or not:

```php
if(isset($fruitArray[$value])){
   $dayArray[$key] = [$value,$fruitArray[$value]);
}
else {
   $dayArray[$key] = [$value];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

check day key available in fruitArray using isset method

```
$dayArray = array('tue','wed','fri','sat');
// print_r($array);
$fruitArray = array (
  'tue' => 'banana',
  'fri' => 'apple',
  'sat' => 'orange',
);
$newTwoDimensionalArray = [];
foreach($dayArray as $day){
  if(isset($fruitArray[$day])){
    $newTwoDimensionalArray[] = [$day,$fruitArray[$day]];
  } else {
    $newTwoDimensionalArray[] = [$day,''];
  }
}
```